# Cloud Fire store returns documents in which fields are undefined

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to fetch data from Fire store into my HTML page. I am receiving a list of documents and I am able to console their document id. But when I try to access any field inside the document it shows undefined.

```
<script type="module">

import { initializeApp } from 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.1.0/firebase-app.js'
import { getFirestore, collection, getDocs} from 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.1.0/firebase-firestore.js'

const firebaseConfig = {........};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const firestore = getFirestore(app);        
const rows = [];

const fetchRows = async () => {
            try {
                const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(firestore, "pdf"));
                querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                var fields = doc.data;
                //console.log(fields);
                rows.push({
                    id : doc.id,
                    title : fields.subject,
                    link : fields.link
                })});
                //console.log(rows);
            }
            catch {
                alert("Notice Download Failed.");
                console.log(error);
            }
        }

fetchRows();
</script>
```

Consoling the fields prints something which I totally don't understand.

```
data(e={}){return super.data(e)}
data(e={}){return super.data(e)}
data(e={}){return super.data(e)}
data(e={}){return super.data(e)}
data(e={}){return super.data(e)}
data(e={}){return super.data(e)}
data(e={}){return super.data(e)}
```

Also consoling any row prints the id correctly but rest are undefined. Eg:

```
{id: '59TnR43fxDSaQf69BbZW', title: undefined, link: undefined}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `var fields = doc.data;` to `var fields = doc.data();`

Comment: thank u so much. cannot believe I missed that.